# Arduino IDE does not include libraries

Tags: compiling, arduino

When I try to compile a code with certain library, I get an error stating that there's no such directory. However the library is already installed properly, it was not supposed to happen. I already tried compiling this code in Windows (with the library installed) and it worked, but in my Ubuntu 22.04 I'm still getting this issue.